# Trigger events using a Webapp in Kaa

Tags: iot, kaa

I am working on a iot application using kaa. My goal is to implement a communication from my dashboard to the endpoints.

1. I have generated events using event class families and successfully
   triggered events using that.
2. I have generated events using android.
3. Is it possible to trigger events to the end points using a web app??? or a Dashboard??
4. Is it possible with Kaa or i have to some external API to use that??? Can Someone help me?? and thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create endpoint application (using Kaa Java SDK) on your server and work with Kaa though it, using for example, JavaScript (you can create your own API), so you can trigger you application, which will send event.

Also, if you need notifications, you can trigger it directly by [REST API method](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#!/Notifications/sendNotification).

Read more in [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/).